# Extract year-month from datetime in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create a new column in the transform data page, where `datetime` data is converted to `year-month`. I used:

```
Format('df'[Date], "YYYY-MM")
```

and it returned:

```
Token Literal expected. Show error.
```

`Date` is in this format:
`10/12/2015`

Expected output:
`12-2015`

Besides, I was able to create this column in the `Data` section but as I open `Transform` in the top toolbar as I would like to groupby and aggregate data, the newly created column is not in the table.

---

Update:

Tried different spelling for `format` and it returned:

```
The name 'FORMAT' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.
```

But it had stated `no error detected` for that particular custom column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the column in the table (next to the visuals) in PowerBI you are using the DAX programming language. This is the "modelling" side of PowerBI. You can create your DAX calculated column as:

```
=FORMAT('df'[Date],"MM-yyyy")
```

When you use "Transform Data", then you are in the ingestion side of PowerBI and you use M language from PowerQuery. Make sure the type of your date column is correct before you apply the formula, if it is not, you can right click the column -> Change Type -> Date.

You can get your date formatted using the below (see the advanced editor). [Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-totext):

```
let
    Source = fn_GenerateDates(#date(2010, 1, 1), #date(2030, 1, 1), null),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "MyCustomFormattedDate", each Date.ToText([Date], "yyyy-MM"))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Or just use the Add Column->Add Custom Column option on the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Hi Murray, thanks for the detailed answer. I checked that `Date` is in `Date` format. However upon clicking on "apply and close" after applying `=FORMAT('df'[Date],"MM-yyyy")` returned `Loading blocked by failures with other queries.` and `The name 'FORMAT' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.` I also tried substituting the spelling with `Format` and `format` but the issue remained. Do you know why the error?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the data sources. If you revert to how your query was before, and refresh the data in the report, what error do you get? Further, if you are in the PowerQuery (by clicking Transform Data), are there any yellow triangles next to your queries / tables. Sound like there is an error in loading data (possibly in a different query) as per the error message.